# How do you make sure that a query always returns a result and sorts the results by relevance?

Tags: php, mysql

Now I have a database set up like the following example:

```
id (int(11)) | name (varchar(20)) | food (varchar(20)) | fastfood (varchar(3)) | pricerange (int(11))

1            | McDonalds          | American           | Yes                   | 1
2            | Outback            | BBQ                | No                    | 2
3            | Mortons            | Steakhouse         | No                    | 3
```

Now I have a user form set up like the following:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET" id="sheet">

    <select name="name1" id="name1">
        <option value="%">No Preference</option>
        <option value="outback">Outback</option>
        <option value="mcdonalds">McDonalds</option>
        <option value="mortons">Mortons</option>
    </select>

    <select name="food1" id="food1">
        <option value="%">No Preference</option>
        <option value="american">American</option>
        <option value="bbq">BBQ</option>
        <option value="steakhouse">Steakhouse</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fast" id="fast">
        <option value="%">No Preference</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

    <select name="price" id="price">
        <option value="%">No Preference</option>
        <option value="1">Cheap</option>
        <option value="2">Middle Ground</option>
        <option value="3">Expensive</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></input>
    <input type="clear" value="Clear" id="Clear"<input>

</form>
```

Now when I run the following query if not all the fields match, I will get no result. How can I manipulate the query to display a result based on best match when I have `int`s & `varchar`s involved?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM .$usertable 
             WHERE $name LIKE '$name' AND 
                   $food LIKE '$food1' AND 
                   $fastfood LIKE '$fast' AND 
                   $pricerange LIKE '$price' ";
```

Fulltext search doesn't work because of the INT and 'OR' will not display the results based on the best match. Let's say the user selected 3 of the 4 options such as: `BBQ | Yes | 2`

Now, the best match in that case would be `Outback`, however because it is trying to match up fast food as well, it will return no result. And if there are even more options it gets even more complicated.

If anyone could shed some light on a solution for this problem I would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Not `AND` but `OR` (which is not `XOR`by the way), so merely some logical combination issue I'd assume from a quick look. For relevance you need to create it which has been outlined in some other questions. Take yourself some time and browse around a bit, and there is a search function, too. Some real gems are hidden on this site, so take some time for searching and reading.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting LIKE to do some things that it doesn't do. LIKE simply does a substring match (e.g., you can cause "Wend" to match "Wendy's"). I'm not sure what it does for integers, but it definitely won't find numbers that are close.

Comment: I have tried the `OR` Statement before. Unfortunately when I replace the `AND` with `OR` it is finding the result, however it is displaying them in a random order by ID and not relevance to the user inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an issue of query syntax. The issue here is defining for your application what you consider to be a "best match". There's no straightforward best match for functions like this: you need to define it yourself. Once you do that you can work on implementing it.

As a simple example, you can define a "best match" as one where as many explicit query parameters as possible match, and int-valued parameters are as close as possible. Then you can compute a "score" for each match, and sort by that.

So suppose the search is `food=BBQ, fastfood=Yes, price=2`. Your query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT *,
    SUM(
        food=:food, -- if food matches, add one to score
        fastfood=:fastfood, -- if fastfood matches, add one to score
        -- finally, add 2 for an exact price match, 1 for off-by-one price match,
        -- 0 for off-by-two matches, etc
        (SELECT MAX(price)-1 from foods)-ABS(price-:price) 
    ) AS score
    FROM foods ORDER BY score DESC
```

You can adjust how important you want each match to be by adjusting how much is added to the score. Also, you can decide if there are different "distances" between categories. E.g., maybe "Steakhouse" is more like "BBQ" than "American" is, so Steakhouse places should score higher.

This is a straightforward approach, but it can be inefficient since you need to calculate a score for each row. You can speed it up with multiple queries: first look for an exact match; if you don't find any, calculate the score for all rows that are partial matches. Only if nothing is still found fall back on a total table search.

```sql
SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food=:food AND fastfood=:fastfood AND price=:price;
-- if no matches then:
SELECT *, SUM(food=:food, fastfood=:fastfood, (SELECT MAX(price)-1 from foods)-ABS(price-:price)) AS score
WHERE food=:food OR fastfood=:fastfood OR price=:price ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Francis, I like the concept here, but I have one questions. Can you assign a `CASE STATEMENT` to assign a value to each match and them calculate the `SUM` of the query?  For Example:
`"SELECT *,
    CASE matches"`

Comment: You can use a case *expression*, or any expression at all which can be coerced to a number. You can only use a case *statement* in a stored procedure. E.g., this is the same as `food=:food`: `CASE food WHEN :food THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. But so is this: `IF(food=:food, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

First you need to parse those ints. These functions may help you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Second, you may manipulate your query so the ints go like `$pricerange <= $price order by $pricerange desc`

(this query would give you first the items with closer pricerange starting from below. you can link it with another with closest priceranges starting from the top with a left join or put a selector to chose from above or from behind the range in case it's not matched. This is only a halfway solution but it works and many search algorithms implement something like that. If you squeeze your brain you may find something closer to what you want, linking querys with `JOIN`, `UNION`, `LIMIT`, etc. Check out those entries on the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/))

Third, you may also use `JOIN` .. `ON NOT NULL` to add criterias to your search. Take a look at [this](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-109030.html) (and, if you don't know how to use join, [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html))

Finally, I recomend you to get familiar with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It's the best way to perform a proper database query in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MySQL look and try the "match against" instruction !
And use "OR" instead of the "AND" ! (match against is the best way i think)

Comment: However right out of the MySQL Book. "Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns." - If there are INT's involved, how would that work?

Comment: If you need to keep the INT for your column (for performance for example), create a second column wich will be the same as the INT column, in a VARCHAR format. It's not a clean solution ... but it will work.
By the way, you can create a column wich will regroup all your possible seeked columns and put all values in séparated by a | for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the MySQL database is not really designed with that sort of thing in mind. It should give you back actually what you ask of it, not perform guesswork for you.

Unfortunately, this means you need to implement this logic in code.  Search for full match, then if that doesn't work, search for cases where certain items match.

The relevence of matches is going to be up to you as a designer.

That is not to say you can't put together a complex query to get the data you are after, you just have to build that logic (perhaps by doing UNIONS on the results of various SELECT statements).

Comment: So have it run the query like above first and if the results are null have it run another query and another query until it finds results? That's going to slow down the search when performed on a large data set won't it?

Comment: I am suggesting that you can do something like SELECT * FROM table WHERE (exact match criteria) UNION SELECT * FROM ta ble WHERE (next best match criteria) UNION SELECT * FROM table W WHERE (next best criteria)... and so on.

Comment: Now, would there be a way to assign a value to each field and instead of finding the best match, it could add up the values and display them in Descending order?

Comment: Certainly,  you could do something like SELECT id, name, food, fastfood, pricerange, (SOME CASE STATEMENTS) as match_value FROM table ORDER BY match_value DESC   Where you can use cases statement to apply values to matches on certain fields and sum up the values

Comment: Again, though, you would need to decide how to weigh the value for each field (or let you user decided what weight to give each) and then build the query logic to match.